# Running Median Curve instead of LOWESS

Tags: r, curve, median

I'm currently working on modifying some R-code I got provided to fit my needs.

The situation is the following:

We are plotting ~200 lines.
They then used LOWESS to get a best-fit curve.

It looks like this right now:

```
lines(lowess(x.lowess, y.lowess), lwd = 3)
```

where x.lowess and y.lowess are the corresponding coordinates, each in a vector, such as:

```
> dput(x.lowess)
c(0.268309377138946, 0.511978097193703, 0.785763175906913, 0.974674880219028, ... )
> dput(y.lowess)
c(0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 0.5, ... )
```

I am now looking the get a running median curve instead of a LOWESS best-fit curve.

Is there any simple way/function for doing this?

for an example of the plot, seee this on flickr (sorry, couldn't upload it directly, i'm new here and it's not allowed :)
[plot with lowess smoothing curve in red](http://www.flickr.com/photos/blabbr/8399215443/in/photostream)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you perhaps show a reproducible example of your data, for example using `dput(x.lowess)` and `dput(y.lowess)`?

Comment: thank you for the answer!
> dput(x.lowess)
c(0.268309377138946, 0.511978097193703, 0.785763175906913, 0.974674880219028, ... )
> dput(y.lowess)
c(0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 0.5, ... )

Comment: to specify more: it is a plot where multiple measurements corresponding to one subject are connected according to the time stamp when the measurement was taken. so to draw all the lines in the first place, the values were sorted by patient, now for lowess, they just used all the measurements and time stamps "together"

Answer (score 2):

Generate some sample data:

```
set.seed(1001)
x <- runif(1000)
y <- runif(1000)
dat <- data.frame(x,y)
```

Use the `quantreg` package to find the median as a function of x:

```
library(quantreg)
q1 <- rq(y~x,data=data.frame(x,y))
xvec <- seq(0,1,length=101)
pq <- predict(q1,newdata=data.frame(x=xvec))
```

Draw in base graphics:

```
plot(x,y,pch=".")
lines(lowess(x,y))
lines(xvec,pq,col=2)
```

Or using `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
qplot(x,y,data=dat,size=I(0.8),alpha=I(0.2))+
    geom_smooth(method="loess")+
    stat_quantile(quantiles=0.5,formula=y~x,colour="red")
```

Comment: Hello! thanks a lot for your answer. I didn't really understand the meaning of `xvec`, so i tried this: `library(quantreg)
x  <- x.lowess
y  <- y.lowess
q1 <- rq(y~x, data=data.frame(x, y))
pq <- predict(q1, newdata=data.frame(x=x.lowess))
lines(x.lowess, pq, col = 2, lwd = 3)`
this gives me a linear slope (i should not that the plotted lines tend to exponential, i added an example of the plot to my question)

Comment: `rq` fits a linear model for the median.  What do you want? A running median?  Using the `loess` function (note not the same as `lowess`) with `family="symmetric"` will do a robust fit -- not a median but maybe closer to what you want ... `xvec` is the vector of x values at which you want to evaluate the fit.

Comment: yes, exactly, a running median would be perfect! sorry, i didn't make myself clear enough...

Comment: done. to be honest, i don't know at all if something like this is even feasible since the time stamps when these measurements are taken, are all different, so there needs to be some sort of regression anyhow... i guess i could also edit x.lowess and y.lowess so as to have them sorted by subject if this helped

Comment: in the end i just made a very clumsy code calculating the medians at differing time stamps with a certain time treshold (+/-) - it works...